# Laravel Controller method not found in GET method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

after define route for edit fields and create function in controller i get this error: `Controller method not found.`

My form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('linksPlugin.edit',$linkFields->id))) }}
...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My Route:

```
Route::controller(
            'linksPlugin','linksPluginManagmentController',
                array(
                                                    ...
                        'getEditLink'            => 'linksPlugin.edit',
                                                    ...
                     )
                 );
```

Controller Action:

```
public function getEditLink($id){
       print_r($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set the form `method` to `GET` it is probably defaulting to `POST`:

```
{{ Form::open(array(
       'route' => array('linksPlugin.edit', $linkFields->id), 
       'method' => 'GET')) }}
```